Usando expresiones regulares en python para identificar uso incorrecto de signos de exclamación
estoy intentando escribir una expresión regular para identificar en un texto oraciones con signos de exclamación mal usados, por ejemplo, que tengan signo de apertura pero no de cierre (Ejemplo: ¡Hola, soy yo). Alguien sabe cómo podría hacerlo usando expresiones regulares? Gracias

Es muy dificil lograr eso con expresiones regulares. Te recomendaría hacerlo usando Python "normal". Si no, tu caso es muy similar a verificar que todos los parentesis tengan su respectivo cierre. Busca sobre ese escenario, y probablemente obtengas un código adecuado.

Concuerdo con @DanteS. Python te ofrece las funciones startswith() y endswith() para la evaluación de Strings. Ya con eso puedes abarcar los extremos de tu cadena a evaluar. Para el cuerpo de la cadena podrías recorrerla y arrojar un error si encuentras cualquier exclamación en posiciones que no sean la primera o la ultima.

He visto a gurús hacer magia negra con REGEX pero para estos casos no es generalmente la herramienta adecuada... No solo debes manejar varios signos de apertura con sus correspondientes de cierre, sino que estos pueden aparecer anidados y aquí las regex se vuelven complicadas, ineficientes e incluso imposibles. Como te recomienda Dante, los algoritmos para comprobar el balanceado/equilibrado de paréntesis te pueden venir muy bien (ejercicio típico de algoritmos/estructuras de datos), una implementación típica es usar una pila (LIFO).

No uses expresiones regulares a menos que sea necesario.
Para validar estructuras anidadas sólo necesitas un contador que sume 1 al entrar y reste 1 al salir de la estructura:
def validar_exclamacion(texto):
    cuenta = 0
    for c in texto:
        if c == "¡":
            cuenta += 1
        elif c == "!":
            cuenta -= 1
            if cuenta < 0:
                break

    return cuenta == 0

La expresión está mal anidada si en algún momento la cuenta es negativa, o al terminar la cuenta no es cero.
Lo mismo puedes usar para validar paréntesis o strings.
Demo
tests = ["un hola",
         "dos hola!",
         "¡hola! chao",
         "¡¡¡ asdfa !!!",
         "¡Una! ¡Dos!",
         "!Reverso¡"]


for test in tests:
    print(test, validar_exclamacion(test))

produce:
un hola True
dos hola! False
¡hola! chao True
¡¡¡ asdfa !!! True
¡Una! ¡Dos! True
!Reverso¡ False

Process finished with exit code 0

